# Change color filling of heatmap (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, heatmap, geom-tile

Im trying to making a heatmap that illustrates how intense a newspaper writes about 6 different meta topics over a time period. I would like each topic to have its own color. The more intense the color is, the more the newspaper writes about it relative to the other meta topics (corresponds to the rel_impact variable in the data set).
So far I have only been able to change the circumference of each box, so the topics get different colors. See the figure below. However, I would like that each box is completly filled out in line with the color scale indicated with the "meta topic" legend instead of the grey color scale.

[image]

My code is:

```
my_palette <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(6, 'Dark2')

metatopic_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = Metatopic, color=Metatopic,fill = rel_impact)) + 
geom_tile() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%Y",expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Dark2", name="Meta topics") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white",high = "black", name=NULL) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = my_palette))) +
  theme_light(base_size = 11) +
  labs(x=NULL, y=NULL)
```

To reproduce the structure of the data, see the following code:

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(14760, 14760, 14760, 14760, 
14760, 14760), class = "Date"), Metatopic = c("Career", "Economics", 
"Industries", "Leisure", "Politics", "Sport"), abs_impact = c(0.00531062385448913, 
0.0569595367458113, 0.0459819861634464, 0.00889034813748066, 
0.0750210871815098, 0.00406422677142547), sum = c(0.196227808854163, 
0.196227808854163, 0.196227808854163, 0.196227808854163, 0.196227808854163, 
0.196227808854163), rel_impact = c(0.0270635639540571, 0.290272500510587, 
0.234329611240884, 0.0453062600525087, 0.382316286461037, 0.0207117777809261
)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), groups = structure(list(date = structure(14760, class = "Date"), 
    .rows = structure(list(1:6), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Do anyone have a suggestions how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the same palette for colour and fill, and adjust opacity (`alpha`) via the `rel_impact`. The following code omits tile borders, which - with tiles that narrow - would mostly override the impression of opacity:

```
metatopic_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = Metatopic, fill = Metatopic, alpha = rel_impact), color = NA) + 
  geom_tile() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%Y",expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2", name="Meta topics") +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = my_palette))) +
  theme_light(base_size = 11) +
  labs(x=NULL, y=NULL)
```

[image: heatmap with opacity]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was exactly what I wanted to do

Comment: You're welcome. I really like the concept of your viz. You could even write the Metatopic in a "headline-ish" font across the heatmap itself, using `geom_text`, although some audiences might find that to playful.